# Consume REST API - send post, receive JSON

Tags: android, json, rest

I`m trying to consume a REST API in Android but the response is returning nil...and in Web client and iOS Client, its returning JSON dictionary

there's my code:

```
  final Handler h = new Handler();
    final Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("onClick!!!");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://applocalize.com.br/rest/rest.php");
            post.setHeader("content-type", "application/text; charset=UTF-8");
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            //Construimos el objeto cliente en formato JSON
            JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();

            try {
                dato.put("pg","categorias");
                dato.put("serv", "buscar");
                dato.put("dt_atualizacao", "0`");

                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
                post.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
                String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                {
                    System.out.println(respStr);
                    JSONArray temp1 = new JSONArray(respStr);
                }
                System.out.println("OKAY!");
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(r1, 5000);
```

Comment: What's the content of `resp.getEntity().getContent()`?

Comment: respStr is '' (empty)

Comment: can you post the code for the web client? (I assume it is a $.ajax of some sort?)

Comment: if you are posting this on a handler, unless your handler is attached to a bg thread, this runs on the ui thread. there should be a big networkonmainthread stacktrace somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend seems to be expecting ValuePairs in your post request, but you're sending a raw jsonobject in the body. Try this:

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pg","categorias"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serv","buscar"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt_atualizacao","0"));
 try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){

        }
```

Comment: I used your code and have commented the following line: `post.setHeader("content-type", "application/text; charset=UTF-8");` Thanks!